What is the worst-case runtime of this algorithm (in big-oh notation)?
The input is an N by N matrix of numbers. Each individual row is increasing from left to right. Each individual column is increasing from top to bottom. The example of a matrix is given below with N = 3.
3   4   5
4   5   8
6   7   9

The following is the basic naive algorithm (in pseudocode) to search for an item in the matrix:
bool search2DMatrix( int a[][], int N)
{
       for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
             for(int j < 0; j < N; j++)
                   if ( item == a[i][j])
                             return true; 
        return false //if not found
}

Find an O(N) worst-case algorithm that finds if a number item is in the matrix.  Write down the algorithm (in pseudocode) and show the analysis of the runtime of the algorithm.
I'm really struggling with trying to understand this and looking online isn't producing any helpful vidoes or resources. Would someone who knows algorithm analysis be able to help me through this problem? I'm taking a data structures class and the professor only posts 2 year old videos and ignores questions. Thank you in advance!
I have made this pseudocode but I don't think this is what the question is asking for.

Start from the top-right corner of the matrix
Now I need to initialize two variables

row with the value 0 is for the top row
column with the value N-1 is for the right column


When row is less than or equal to N-1 and column is greater than or equal to 0 then repeat the steps 4, 5, and 6
Compare the value at the current position matrix[row][column] with the target value X

If they are equal then return true because X exists in the matrix
If the value at the current position is greater than X move to the left column by descending column
If the value at the current position is less than I move to the next row by ascending row


If I have exhausted all possible positions and haven't found X return false


Your algorithm is O(N^2) in the worst case.

Your initial naiive algorithm is already O(N), not ON(^2).  N in asymptotic notation isn't the argument that's passed in, it's the size of your input.  The fact you're calling the width/height N is just a confusing name on your part.  If you had taken a separate width and height, it'd be more obvious that you have to search width * height cells, and that corresponds to the total size of your input (i.e., the algorithm is O(N)).

@StephenNewell The size of data is N^2. In the example N=3 and there are 9 elements in the matrix.

@trincot Yes, I did. And I also read the original post "the input is an N by N matrix of numbers" and that the algorithm has to be O(N) where N = number of rows = number of columns, not the total size of data.
IMVHO, assuming that both columns and rows of the matrix are increasing sequences it is possible to create an algorithm that requires <= 2*N steps.

Sure, @Yuri, that is so. I just didn't think your previous comment showed understanding of Stephen's reasoning.

@StephenNewell Asymptotic notation can be used for anything, and OP clearly laid out N is the dimension of the matrix. You might be confusing the definition of complexity classes with asymptotic notation.

why this is closed? looks reasonable question

The trick to make it O(N) is to not start in the top-left cell of the matrix, but in the bottom-left cell of the matrix. At that position you are in the middle of an ordered sequence of 2N-1 items that run from (0, 0) to (n-1, 0) further to (n-1, n-1).
Now if the current cell has a value that is greater than the target value, then you know that all values at the right of the current cell are no longer relevant: we can move up one row (to row n-2). If at some point the value is less than what we look for, we can discard the column we are in, and move to column 1. And so we narrow down to the target cell.
Here is how that looks in code (I'd expect that you should pass item as an argument):
bool search2DMatrix(int a[][], int N, int item) {
    int r = N - 1;
    int c = 0;
    while (r >= 0 && c < N) {
        if (a[r][c] == item) return true;
        if (a[r][c]  > item) r--;
        else                 c++;
    }
    return false;
}

This way your loop will make at the most 2N-1 iterations, with at the most 2N evaluations of the loop condition.

In fact, that logic can be applied/adapted wherever you start in the matrix.

Thank you so much, everyone. I will read back through the book pdfs she gave the class white this on my other screen to try and better understand. I appreciate the aid friends!

@Rafat, let me know if this answer suited your needs. If you wish to do so, you can also mark the answer as accepted, but it is optional.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès im interested how you can do it from top left corner
